# Is it possible to remove the printing icon on windows in Win10?

Tags: windows-10

> **Spoiler-Update**: Solved by closing this task:
>    [image: Solution]

I noticed this green thing on a external remote desktop.
Clicked on it - turned out it was a print-button. - Somehow it annoyed me xD
Any way to get rid of this (with limited rights - I'm not admin)?
Or is this just hardcoded in the installer I'm using?
[image: Print-Button]

> **Updates**
>   I noticed it also appears in other installers:
>   [image: Print-Button 2nd Example]
>   And even other apps have it, I think all actually - but only when the window is focused
>   [image: Focused]
>   [image: Not focused]
>   There are not printers setup either:
>   [image: No printers]

Comment: You tried another installer? Either way, that button is not standard so it's some app either adding it or it's from the installer itself

Comment: It is a real eye-sore. It would annoy me too. I have never seen this and I've been a system admin for 25 years. It looks like it is something specific to this installer. Or something added to that computer by some 3rd party software (it is not part of Windows itself). Maybe some printing utility installed on the system?

Comment: @CaldeiraG I added another screenshot - it shows in other installers too

Comment: Does this only show up in installers or does it also show up on other programs such as Word, Calculator, Paint, etc.? To me this looks like a button added by a print driver or something like that. What remote desktop software are you using?

Comment: Seems like it's added by some installed product.

Comment: This button is still in Windows Vista/7 style. The software adding it is probably rather outdated.

Comment: @MMM Yes, I noticed it in Explorer and Paint too - added an example screenshot in the question - I think the software is called "Check Point SSL Network Extender"

Comment: You almost certainly have an extra process in your process list responsible for this ugly thing.  Services can't do this and a shell extension wouldn't work on anything outside of the explorer.  Look at your process list and you will likely find your answer.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That was it - thanks! I deleted a bunch of processes until it disappeared...I can't remember what the process' name was though, something with `hardcopy` -.-

Comment: Hardcopy application creates by default a green icon on all other forms. To keep Hardcopy application installed, but to remove the green printer icon (which can also be configured  as a blue printer icon) we have to change all quick settings "Printer icon". to "No function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client is running a tool called [Hardcopy](http://www.gen.hardcopy.de/) in the background. In order to get rid of the button, go to Settings → Options → Printer Icon, or just turn off the entire program if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the green icon, we have to right-click on the Hardcopy icon in the tray. Then select Show Window and go to Quick Settings and select "No Function" for all functions involving "Printer icon". The icon will then disappear.

Comment: Even if somebody gave a negative rating to my answer, I still come to my own message to remove the printer icon, because it works :)